# Dump a list of files on a JSON file in c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am learning to write JSON and I have done this:

```
        try
        {
            string path = @"C:\";
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.exe");
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"filelist.json"))

                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    FolderFiles aFile = new FolderFiles
                    {
                        FileName = dir.ToString(),
                        FileType = Path.GetExtension(path + @"\" + dir.ToString())
                    };

                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(file, aFile);
                }
            MessageBox.Show("Process Done");
        }
```

I am trying to dump a list of filenames in a JSON files, but when I validate it says that it is invalid, and also it is only on a one line when I opened it.

Can JSON write to a file like a sequential order.
Any help will be great, thanks

Current output:

```
{"FileName":"C:\\Users\\Joko\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Research\\GetFilesFromFolder\\GetFilesFromFolder\\bin\\Debug\\GetFilesFromFolder.exe","FileType":".exe"}{"FileName":"C:\\Users\\Joko\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Research\\GetFilesFromFolder\\GetFilesFromFolder\\bin\\Debug\\GetFilesFromFolder.vshost.exe","FileType":".exe"}
```

This is the FolderFiles:

```
internal class FolderFiles {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the example of expected output file content?

Comment: Very confusing what you actually expect - you are writing some sequence of JSON objects into stream... Result obviously would not be JSON... Maybe you are looking to JSON serialize array of `FolderFiles`?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to write to a JSON file sequentially using out of box tools in .NET. You would have to implement that by yourself, manually writing to a file piece by piece.

Instead, just build the object containing an array of your folder paths, serialize it to JSON and just write it all at once to a file.

Examplary code to implement that, with hardcoded data you've provided as example output:

```
public class FolderFilesAggregate
{
    public IEnumerable<FolderFiles> FolderFiles { get; set; }
}

public class FolderFiles
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get your folder files in any way you want to, I hardcoded it to simplify the example
        var folderFiles = new List<FolderFiles>
                          {
                              new FolderFiles
                              {
                                  FileName = @"C:\\Users\\Joko\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Research\\GetFilesFromFolder\\GetFilesFromFolder\\bin\\Debug\\GetFilesFromFolder.exe",
                                  FileType = ".exe"
                              },
                              new FolderFiles
                              {
                                  FileName = @"C:\\Users\\Joko\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Research\\GetFilesFromFolder\\GetFilesFromFolder\\bin\\Debug\\GetFilesFromFolder.vshost.exe",
                                  FileType = ".exe"
                              }
                          };

        var folderFilesAggregate = new FolderFilesAggregate
                                   {
                                       FolderFiles = folderFiles
                                   };

        // serialize your aggregate object
        var serializedFolderFilesAggregate = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folderFilesAggregate, Formatting.Indented);

        // write it to a file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.json", serializedFolderFilesAggregate);
    }
}
```